# Total length of a complex curve

Tags: objects, measurement

I have a complex curve which is a series of vertices and I would like to find the total length of all the vertices. MeasureIT can show me the length of each segment in the curve but does not seem to offer a total length. Is there any tool that can do this?[image]

Answer (score 11):

MeasureIt addon also gives the total sum of values.
It's displayed under the measurements list.

1. Select all the edges you want to measure
2. Select a "measure group" like 'A' (or it won't work)
3. Click the <kbd>Segment</kbd> button to calculate

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Sverchok addon

https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok

[image]

Comment: or even use object in + path length (sum) + sthetoscope