# Getting the total length of all edges using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm trying to get the total length of all edges of an object / fractal while in geometry nodes.

I looked at this [Total length of a complex curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185748/total-length-of-a-complex-curve) which works I also looked at this [Total length of a complex curve with many points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275033/total-length-of-a-complex-curve-with-many-points) but I was wondering if geometry nodes has the same ability to show the total edge lengths?

[image: img1]

I tried using the **curve length node** but that number seems to be just for the original icosphere and not the other little icospheres attached to it.
it **should be 182.95** but it says **31.54**

[image: img2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply because you only have the original icosphere as a curve in your geometry, others are instances. Use a `Realize Instances` to convert them back to curves and `Curve Length` should work:

[image]

Comment: There's a better solution (especially for fractals, because they tend to be computationally expensive) given the assumption the scaling is scalar (equal on all 3 axes) - sum up the scale of all instances and multiply by the length calculated for just one instance; this way you don't realize instances. Not sure, but I think if the scaling differs on axes you can just calculate total distance per each axis? I would have to reason about this…